# how to add current active user as foreign key to the create post model in djangorestframework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

how to add current active user as foreign key to the create post model in djangorestframework ?

models:

```
class DoctorProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(_('mobile'), unique=True, max_length=10, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'),max_length=25,blank=False)
    otp = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
      
class Doctor_clinic(models.Model):
    clinic_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    doc_profile = models.ForeignKey(DoctorProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clinic_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    clinic_address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pincode = models.IntegerField()
```

#how to get the forign key in serializers

## I wrote in this way, is this correct/relevent?

```
   class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        # mobile = serializers.RegexField("[0-9]{10}",min_length=10,max_length=10)
        password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
        email=serializers.EmailField(max_length=155,min_length=3,required=True)
        name=serializers.CharField(max_length=55,min_length=3,required=True)

        class Meta:
            model = DoctorProfile
            fields = ("name", "email", "password", "mobile","otp")

class ClinicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor_clinic
        fields =('clinic_name','clinic_address', 'City', 'state', 'pincode','doc_profile')
```

views:

```
class ClinicRegistrationView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ClinicSerializer
    queryset = Doctor_clinic.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

permissions.py

use permission classes

class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):

```
 def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
     return obj.doc_profile == request.user
```

views.py

```
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(doc_profile=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

When serializing relations you need to define a seperate field depending on the representation you want, for example write your serializer like this:

```
class ClinicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    doc_profile = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Doctor_clinic
        fields =('clinic_name','clinic_address', 'City', 'state', 'pincode','doc_profile')
```

Comment: showing this error,                                                                                     django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: doccure_doctor_clinic.doc_profile_id

Comment: that means that one of your clinics is missing a doctor `ForeignKey`, try adding it via admin and try again

Comment: can you check my views and let me know if itll be fine ?

Comment: your view seems fine, its the objects that already exist in your database that are most likely causing this issue, try setting `null=True` on your `doc_profile` field in your `Doctor_clinic` class

Comment: data saved sucessfully but , Forign key is saving null, how to know which user is storing data?

Comment: define a `__str__` method in your referenced class and return some value as a string, for example: `def __str__(self): return self.name` and see if it helps, you can also use different type of field, see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: doccure_doctor_clinic.doc_profile_id, doccure_doctor_clinic.clinic_name
, this error  is showing

Comment: that means you have 2 clinics with the same name or are trying to create one with the name that was taken, try deleting yourdatabase if you can and starting a new

Comment: Thank you SLDem , one tutorial answer is solved this problem

Comment: May I ask (for myself) what solution did you use?

Comment: using permissions of authenticate user in views
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(doc_profile=self.request.user)